# android alarmmanager repeat every month in specified date

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm developing an application that can send a SMS in specified time, I have add some function on it, but i get stumped while i add function that can send a sms in every month on 14th, how can i make that function?

i have try the answer code on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227035/android-repeat-alarm-for-every-monday-or-every-tuesday) but didn't work.

I presume the problem is on the interval parameter in setRepeating function of AlarmManager class

```
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval , pendingIntent);
```

what the proper value of variable interval?

Answer (score 1):

here interval is time in milliseconds between two alarms.

```
 //e.g
long interval=5*60*1000;

mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval , pendingIntent);
```

then my alarm will repeat every after 5 mins.

**EDIT**

```
 int days=GetTotalDays(current_month);
    interval=(days)*24*60*60*1000;

    public int GetTotalDays(int current_month)
    {
    //here u can fetch current months total days
    //suppose current month is 6(means july as it starts from 0)
    //& u want to set alarm to next month(august)
    //so get remaining days from calender of current month  +  day of next month
    //e.g(14-7 to 14-8)  so 
    //remaining days from calender of current month = 18(14-7 to 31-7)
    //day of next month =14.
    //so return would be (18+14-2=30).(-2.as it takes currentdate and nextdate also in   calculation)
int currentdate=14;
int nextdate=14;
int totalDays=getDaysInMonthInPresentYear(6);
int myDays=(totalDays-currentdate)+nextdate;
return myDays-2;

    }


public static int getDaysInMonthInPresentYear(int monthNumber)
 {
 int days=0;
 if(monthNumber>=0 && monthNumber<12){
 try
 {
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 int date = 1;
 int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 calendar.set(year, monthNumber, date);
 days = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 } catch (Exception e)
 {
 if(e!=null)
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 return days;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I know that. interval 5 mins is static, but interval every month could be different. for example 14th june to 14th july might be different with 14th july to 14th august. any other solution?

Comment: just try to put interval=30*24*60*60..i have not tried..but every month has its different days like 28,30,31..so may b u can fetch time in millis using (new Date()).& then set interval.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, I will try your edited answer and tell you the result

Comment: your answer is work but 'return myDays-2' should be 'return myDays' and 'interval=(days)*24*60*60*1000;' should be 'long interval=(long)(days)*24*60*60*1000;' this code only work once and doesn't work on second next month.

Comment: i think this problem become imposible to be solved by setRepeat() because interval is always static and always has a fixed value while the number of days in each month may vary

Comment: Yes but u can set interval to public static or take it in sharedPreference.. & u can change it in pendingIntent.so when alarm manager will be called it set the interval .

Comment: thanks for helping, your answer inspire me to solve the problem. I do not use setrepeat() but using the method set() as usual. This method will not involve interval. and I would call the method every time alarm goes off, of course with new triger time. so once again thanks for helping, i will mark your answer as a useful answer

Answer (score 0):

```
alarmManager .setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar1.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*30,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*30, pendingIntent);
```

You can try like this

Comment: What about the months having not exactly 30 days?